# FormAuthentication with multiple login pages in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, friendly-url, form-authentication

I'm trying to achieve FormAuthentication with multiple login pages by following this solution:
[FormsAuthentication with multiple login pages](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19740.forms-authentication-with-multiple-login-pages.aspx)

Basically the concept is to have a "middle page" that redirect you to the respective Login page of respective folder.

But I can't get this to work if I have friendly URL enabled in my application, I simply get a Redirection Loop error.

Please advise what should I do to achieve FormAuthentication with multiple login page.

P/S: I know FormAuthentication limit to have only one Login page, this is just how it being designed, a work around like the "middle page" is not a really good solution.

I been thinking to implement login myself without using FormAuthentication, but I do not have any idea how should I do it.

In one of the application I wrote previously, I store UserId in Session and use Session["LoggedIn"] = 1 to indicate the user are good to go, but I always have Session expiry issues. I know I should use Cookies but I not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally figure out a solution for this (perhaps a work around)

Instead of putting the Login Form inside each folder, put each Login Form in the root, then use the same concept of "middle page" and redirect them respectively.

In the Login page OnLoad function, just check if User is authenticated and have specific roles, then redirect them to the respective folder, so they wont need to signin again if they already signed in.

Answer (score 0):

if possible, just use one log-in form and use different web.config files in different directories, or one web.config with special s.

if not possible, web.config files might still help.

ex: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316871

Comment: Hi I had actually thinking to use single log-in form but because I have different db table to check so I can't do this, but anyway I had figured out a solution myself, thks!